# back button gives error message when selected li is less than selected index?

Tags: javascript, html

So i've got some JS I use to switch tabs on a single page. hitting the next button until the end stops, and will not throw an error message. but when i use the back button to go all the way to the first selected li item, it gives me this error: VM6813 astral.php:844 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
at HTMLAnchorElement.btPrev.onclick (VM6813 astral.php:844:37)
btPrev.onclick @ VM6813 astral.php:844

Why would it give that error, when hitting next will not?

```
const
      navSub_LI = document.querySelectorAll('#navsub > li'),
      contents = document.querySelectorAll('#Contents > article'),
      btNext = document.querySelector('#bt-next'),
      btPrev = document.querySelector('#bt-prev'),
      setContent = ref => contents.forEach((article, i) => article.classList.toggle('noDisplay', article.dataset.ref !== ref));
    navSub_LI.refIndex = [...navSub_LI].findIndex(li => li.classList.contains('active'))
    setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)

    navSub_LI.forEach((li, indx, arr) => {
      li.onclick = () => {
        navSub_LI.refIndex = indx
        setContent(navSub_LI[indx].dataset.ref)
        arr.forEach(z => z.classList.toggle('active', z === li))
      }
    })
    btNext.onclick = () => {
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex++].classList.remove('active')
      if (navSub_LI.refIndex >= navSub_LI.length) navSub_LI.refIndex--
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.add('active')
      setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)
    }
    btPrev.onclick = () => {
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex--].classList.remove('active')
      if (navSub_LI.refIndex >= navSub_LI.length) navSub_LI.refIndex++
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.add('active')
      setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)
    }
```

@Barmar posted the solution below in the comments, here it is and it works flawlessly!

```
const
      navSub_LI = document.querySelectorAll('#navsub > li'),
      contents = document.querySelectorAll('#Contents > article'),
      btNext = document.querySelector('#bt-next'),
      btPrev = document.querySelector('#bt-prev'),
      setContent = ref => contents.forEach((article, i) => article.classList.toggle('noDisplay', article.dataset.ref !== ref));
    navSub_LI.refIndex = [...navSub_LI].findIndex(li => li.classList.contains('active'))
    setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)

    navSub_LI.forEach((li, indx, arr) => {
      li.onclick = () => {
        navSub_LI.refIndex = indx
        setContent(navSub_LI[indx].dataset.ref)
        arr.forEach(z => z.classList.toggle('active', z === li))
      }
    })
    btNext.onclick = () => {
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex++].classList.remove('active')
      if (navSub_LI.refIndex >= navSub_LI.length) navSub_LI.refIndex--
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.add('active')
      setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)
    }
    btPrev.onclick = () => {
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex--].classList.remove('active')
       if (navSub_LI.refIndex < 0) navSub_LI.refIndex++
      navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.add('active')
      setContent(navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref)
    }
```

Comment: `if (navSub_LI.refIndex >= navSub_LI.length)` should be `if (navSub_LI.refIndex < 0)`

Comment: Why don't you just check if you're already at `0` and just return, rather than decrementing the index and then incrementing it again.

Comment: I'm not very well versed when it comes to Javascript. I was trying to figure out how to enable or disable/hide/show the next and back buttons based on if the last tab is selected hide next button or disable it, and if the first tab is selected hide or disable the back button